# Why does this hashmap solution only work sometimes for longest substring leetcode question

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

I was wondering if someone could help me understand why my hashmap solution for longest substring without repeating characters only works sometimes?

```
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
      // Type your solution here
    let hashmap = {};
    let largestCount = 0; 
    let curCount = 0;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < s.length;i++){
        
        let letter = s[i];
        if(hashmap[letter]){
            if(curCount >= largestCount){
                largestCount = curCount
            }
            hashmap = {};
            curCount = 0;
            i--;
        }else{
            hashmap[letter] = 1;
            
            curCount++;
        };
    };
    
    
    
    if(curCount >= largestCount){
        largestCount = curCount;
    };
    
    return largestCount;
};
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Please don't assume we know all the Leetcode problems.

Comment: Do you have examples of input where it doesn't work?

Comment: Does it not work with specific inputs, or does it work with only specific inputs. Because theres a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you find a repeating character, you only go back 1 character with `i--`. You need to go back to the next character after the beginning of the current substring. So change

```
i--;
```

to

```
i -= curCount;
```

You could make it more efficient by storing the index of the character in the hash map, instead of always 1. Then when you find a repeated character, you could use

```
i = hashMap[letter];
```

But since `0` is a valid index, you'll also have to change

```
if (hashMap[letter])
```

to

```
if (hashMap.hasOwnProperty(letter))
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe with an inverse :

```
 for(let i = 0; i < s.length;i++){
        
        let letter = s[i];
        if(!hashmap[letter]){
           
hashmap[letter] = 1;
            
            curCount++;

        }else{
             if(curCount >= largestCount){
                largestCount = curCount
            }
            hashmap = {};
            curCount = 0;
            i--;
        };
    };
```